# Как экранировать неизвестное заранее количество слешей

Tags: php, экранирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно экранировать неизвестное заранее количество слешей в данных, которые будут загружаться в БД?

Насколько я поняла (не владею пхп, к сожалению), именно код ниже отвечает за экранирование спецсимволов. Поправьте, если я ошибаюсь.
Сейчас код такой:

```
function clearString($str){
return trim(preg_replace('/[^%a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9 ,\/.+-]/iu','',$str));
```

Но бывает, что исходные данные,загружаемые в БД, представлены в таком виде:

***КУ, н/дом, ОС, евро, встр/кух, д/1/пары, б/в/п***

или:

***КУ, н/дом, д/1-3/пары/РФ, б/дет/жив, зЛ, инт-т***

Вариантов сокращений с использованием слеша - тысячи. Заранее предсказать их количество невозможно

По этой причине (я так думаю), в БД иногда загружаются данные, которые не могут быть корректно отображены. И я получаю ошибки.

Здесь, видимо, должно быть что-то вроде /*/ или / /  ?
Или даже /*/*/ или / / /  ?
Как мне написать правильно? Поисковики не помогли, увы.

А, может, я совсем не в ту степь забрела? Сориентируйте, пожалуйста, куда "копать"?
Спасибо!

Comment: Вы хотите из `КУ, н/дом, д/1-3/пары/РФ, б/дет/жив, зЛ, инт-т` получить `КУ, н\/дом, д\/1-3\/пары\/РФ, б\/дет\/жив, зЛ, инт-т`? Или я неправильно понял?

Comment: Ничего экранировать не надо.

Comment: А где, я извиняюсь, вы хотите корректно отображать эти исходные данные?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы они без ошибок записывались в БД,откуда потом они будут выводиться в html

Comment: Для экранирования данных перед вставкой в MySQL необходимо использовать только одну штатную функцию, которая специально предназначена для этих целей: mysqli_real_escape_string(). После того, как вы достали данные из БД их следует экранировать для вывода, например htmlspecialchar(). Предложенный вами способ изменяет данные, mysqli_real_escape_string() позволяет хранить данные в том виде, в котором они к вам поступили, т.е. без изменений.

Comment: Miron, спасибо! Если оформите комментарий в ответ, я смогу выбрать его лучшим.

Comment: @Miron открою маленький секрет:  mysqli_real_escape_string() **не предназначена** для экранирования данных перед вставкой в MySQL. **Настоятельно** рекомендую перестать тиражировать эту глупость.

Comment: @Наталья к счастью, не сможете.

Comment: Да ладно, бросьте вводить в заблуждение и почитайте мануал: "mysqli_real_escape_string экранирует специальные символы в строке для использования в SQL-выражении, используя текущий набор символов соединения". Или вы считаете себя умнее тех, кто создавал документацию по PHP? :)

Comment: @Наталья - модератор заблокировал возможность отвечать на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Ну, что ж. Значит, здесь напишу Большое спасибо еще раз!